# Network file-sharing between Linux and Android

Tags: networking, fedora, samba, android, file-sharing

I want to share the contents of my external HDD with my Android phone.

For the last two hours, I've been trying to correctly set up Samba - it was absolutely horrible.

There must be another, simpler way to set up file sharing over a (W)LAN, because learning 200 new shell commands in a hostile and unknown environment definitely isn't something I want to waste my time on.

Is something as FTP my solution?

Comment: There are a variety of solutions -- probably hundreds of them. The solution that is most relevant to this site might be OwnCloud. There's an OwnCLoud Android app, but it also works with other apps. Here are some links: 
  http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/build-your-own-cloud

  http://lifehacker.com/5993596/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-cloud-storage-service-in-five-minutes-with-owncloud

  http://techsplurge.com/2456/6-top-applications-android-stream-music-videos-pc/

Comment: other solutions might include AirDroid, FolderSync or (my favorite) DigiControl (and DigiSSHD).

Comment: You might also be interested in [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) which is a great tool to simplify setting up all sorts of networking stuff. I always use it to set up my SMB shares and it takes a couple of minutes rather than the long hours I had spent trying to figure it out in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the occasional file share there's [WOOF (Web Offer One File)](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/woof.html). Woof is trivial to use. It offers files over HTTP and also allows files to be uploaded. Here's the usage:

```
 Usage: woof [-i <ip_addr>] [-p <port>] [-c <count>] <file>
           woof [-i <ip_addr>] [-p <port>] [-c <count>] [-z|-j|-Z|-u] <dir>
           woof [-i <ip_addr>] [-p <port>] [-c <count>] -s
           woof [-i <ip_addr>] [-p <port>] [-c <count>] -U
```

To offer up a file:

```
$ woof filename
```

You can control whether it allows a file to be downloaded/uploaded by including the `-U` switch. All that's required is a browser to interact with `woof`.

#### Example

```
$ woof Software\ Development\ Guide.docx
Now serving on http://192.168.1.20:8080/Software%20Development%20Guide.docx
```